# Spring Boot INSERT parameters

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, sql-insert

I need to update person_id in person class in my spring project.Code part is as follows.But insert query does not work in the repository part. do I need to send it one by one as a parameter?

```
public void save(){
     List<Person> personList = service.findByAll();
            for (Person person : personList) {
                personRepository.getNextSequence(person);
            }
    }


@Repository
   public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
    
        @Modifying
        @Query(value = "INSERT INTO PERSON(person_id,name) VALUES(PERSON_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,:person.name) ", nativeQuery = true)
        public void getNextSequence( Person  person);
    
     }
```

Comment: Why? Why not just call `save` on the `PersonRepository` and let JPA handle it. You are currently using JPA and trying very hard to work around it.

Comment: I'm creating a new record with save, what I want is to change the id of the existing record.

Comment: You are doing an insert that is creating a new record.

Comment: I'm sorry I explained it incompletely, the old id information will stop, I need to create  a new id clone actually.

Comment: Then create a new person, copy the data (without the id) and call save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to save the same object with a new ID, you must detach the entity, set the ID as 0 and save it. This will save the same object with a new ID.

So the code would be something like:

```
// somewhere in the code
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;    

List<Person> personList = service.findByAll();

for (Person person : personList) {
    entityManager.detach(person);
    person.setId(0);
}

personRepository.saveAll(personList);
```